# React select option overlaped by other component

Tags: react-select

my react-select option is overlaped by other component like this,

[image: myReact-select]

i have added the styles to the Select tag,

```
<Select options={this.state.industries} 
   styles={{
     menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 })
   }}
   {...}
 }}/>
```

and set the z-index of the card like so

```
.quick-solution-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 40px;
}
```

am i missing something on my code?